# PHP add values from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two php arrays that are in different orders. I want to find the correct array from array one and array two and add them together based on the values from `currency`, `itemsSold` and `total`. I also need to group them by `currency` and `PaymentType`.

First Array

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'department' => 'Mens',
    'itemsSold' => 4566,
    'paymentType' => 'Cash;Card;Voucher',
    'total' => 4800,
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'department' => 'womens',
    'itemsSold' => 6221,
    'paymentType' => 'Cash;Card;Voucher',
    'total' => 9888,
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'department' => 'Home',
    'itemsSold' => 20,
    'paymentType' => 'Cash;Card;Voucher',
    'total' => 17233,
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'GBP',
    'department' => 'Home',
    'itemsSold' => 20,
    'paymentType' => 'Voucher',
    'total' => 677,
  ),
  4 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'department' => 'Home',
    'itemsSold' => 20,
    'paymentType' => 'Voucher',
    'total' => 17233,
  )
)
```

Second Array

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'department' => 'Mens',
    'itemsSold' => 12,
    'paymentType' => 'Cash;Card;Voucher',
    'total' => 11,
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'department' => 'Home',
    'itemsSold' => 20,
    'paymentType' => 'Cash;Card;Voucher',
    'total' => 500,
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'department' => 'womens',
    'itemsSold' => 8,
    'paymentType' => 'Cash;Card;Voucher',
    'total' => 1277,
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'GBP',
    'department' => 'Home',
    'itemsSold' => 20,
    'paymentType' => 'Voucher',
    'total' => 677,
  ),
  4 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'department' => 'Home',
    'itemsSold' => 40,
    'paymentType' => 'Voucher',
    'total' => 17233,
  )
)
```

Desired Array

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'department' => 'Mens',
    'itemsSold' => 4578,
    'paymentType' => 'Cash;Card;Voucher',
    'total' => 4811,
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'department' => 'Home',
    'itemsSold' => 40,
    'paymentType' => 'Cash;Card;Voucher',
    'total' => 1856,
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'department' => 'womens',
    'itemsSold' => 6229,
    'paymentType' => 'Cash;Card;Voucher',
    'total' => 11165,
  ),
  3 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'GBP',
    'department' => 'Home',
    'itemsSold' => 40,
    'paymentType' => 'Voucher',
    'total' => 1354,
  ),
  4 =>
  array (
    'currency' => 'USD',
    'department' => 'Home',
    'itemsSold' => 60,
    'paymentType' => 'Voucher',
    'total' => 34466,
  
)
```

As you can see, the values have been added together to give the total in a new array.

I have tried `array_merge()` but that just adds the arrays in each-other so the `desired array` is 6 items long, it doesn't add the values of the arrays together.

I tried looping foreach though `first array` and then using the index to find the items in the `second array` but the index changes as the arrays can be in any order.

I'm very new to programming and especially PHP, so I would appreciate a detailed answer that helps me learn it.

Thanks

Comment: In short, you want to sum values by department? Then it's the department you need to compare, not the index.

Comment: Even after the edit, you can still apply the principle from the answer. Just construct a key from concatenating all the values you want to group on.

Answer (score 0):

Short version of code, `$a1` and `$a2` are your arrays:

```
$newarray = [];
// rebuild array so as key is unique value, 
// in your case it is 'department':
foreach ($a1 as $item) {
    $newarray[$item['department']] = $item;


    // Or if you group by both currency and department:
    $key = $item['department'] . $item['currency'];
    $newarray[$key] = $item;
}

foreach ($a2 as $item) {
    $department = $item['department'];
    if (isset($newarray[$department])) {
        $newarray[$department]['itemsSold'] += $item['itemsSold'];
        $newarray[$department]['total'] += $item['total'];
    }

    // Or if you group by both currency and department:
    $key = $item['department'] . $item['currency'];
    if (isset($newarray[$key])) {
        $newarray[$key]['itemsSold'] += $item['itemsSold'];
        $newarray[$key]['total'] += $item['total'];
    }
}

$newarray = array_values($newarray);
print_r($newarray);
```

Full fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/7h0qu).

Comment: Hey, firstly, thank you for your reply. I really appreciate it. I messed up and I need to also group by two other columns. I updated my answer. If you could answer that I would be extremely greatful. I'm sorry my initial post was wrong and for wasting any time.

Comment: Create a unique key for `$newarray`. What is it now? Department and currency? So: `$newarray[$item['department'] . $item['currency']] = $item;` Also don't forget to edit second `foreach` loop.

Comment: You can set __any key__ you want for `$newarray`. And you need each key of this array to be __unique__.

Comment: @JamesG The keys in question here are mere helper keys that make grouping easier. They are discarded at the end through `array_values`. No keys inside the elements are changed.

Comment: Sample fiddle for currency and department: https://3v4l.org/dvP4C Also updated the answer.

Comment: @u_mulder if I change one of the currencies to `EUR`. It does not seem to change the output at all: https://3v4l.org/uDu6q

Comment: Because `EUR` currency is not in first array. So, you have just add this element to result array manually, no?